# How do I create a text field in registration that only shows up if a checkbox is checked?

Tags: forms

I am making a registration process in which there needs to be a text field that only appears if a checkbox is "on". I would think "parent" fields would do this, but whenever I click the "parent" dropdown under account settings, the only option is "none". If I am being too vague, feel free to let me know and I will clarify.

Thank you,

Alex

Comment: do you have some Form API code and PHP code that is trying to do this -- care you share your function / code ?

Comment: I have nothing but Drupal 7 Commons distribution, no additional snippets. I feel like I'm just missing something on how to enable parent fields. I'm pretty much a complete noob so writing scripts for drupal is beyond my current skillset.

Comment: Sorry i was confused when you said:
*I am making a registration process in which there needs to be a text field that only appears if a checkbox is "on".* It implies -- you've made something; or have something partial. Did you try installing the [conditional_fields module](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields). I'm not sure its settings affects the registration page; but i think so.

Comment: Hi there. What have you tried? Looking at your tags, you should be able to find the answer with proper search query to one of internet search engines.

Answer (score 1):

[Conditional Fields](https://drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) seems to be what you are looking for.

> Conditional Fields for Drupal 7 is an user interface to the new [States API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_process_states/7), plus the ability to modify fields appearance and behavior on certain conditions when viewing content.

Especially their example use case seems to match exactly your checkbox - text field need:

> When editing a node (or any other entity type that supports fields, like **users** and categories), the dependent fields are dynamically modified with the States API.
>   You can, for example, define a custom “Article teaser" **field that is shown only if a** "Has teaser" **checkbox is checked**.

Emphasis mine.